# How do I set cURL options in a custom migration?

Tags: 8, migrations

I have a custom migration that needs to get JSON data from a remote URL. This works fine in a beta environment outside of ddev, but I'm having trouble in a ddev test environment because of SSL on the other end.

It seems the cURL option `SSL_VERIFYHOST` is set to `false`, but that's clearly not happening when the migration tries to run. I'm using the Migrate, the Migrate Tools, and the Migrate Plus modules; I saw that another module, Migration Tools, might allow me to set the cURL options, but I get a dependency error when trying to enable it. Core and modules are all updated.

Comment: The plugin that does the fetching should provide a way to pass configuration to the plugin, in this case, to set SSL_VERIFYHOST to false. Since the HTTP plugin in Migrate Plus uses the httpClient, you should be able to pass verify: false as an option that gets passed along to the Guzzle constructor. Although it looks like the http plugin only supports headers and authentication options - you could simply extend the Http plugin to add this option and then use that plugin in your migration YAML.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me a hint where I can find the http plugin? is it in core, web/modules, somewhere else? I might be able to work with your suggestion if I could locate it...Never mind, I found it (I think) in migrate_plus

Comment: Yes, thats the one.

Comment: @AnnieG I came across this patch for migration tools  https://www.drupal.org/project/migration_tools/issues/3031705 however I am not sure where to add this in my custom module yml. Where in migrate_plus did you set/find this option?